# ES5: 'use strict' within dependency fails to be minified by Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, ecmascript-5, webhose

I am trying to deploy on Heroku, where I'm given the following error:
`remote: Failed to minify the code from this file: 
remote: ./node_modules/webhoseio/webhoseio.js:13`

Upon inspecting this dependency, I found that it uses the ES5 `'use strict';` declaration. How can I have Heroku compile this dependency?

EDIT: Package.json file
`{
  "name": "stocks-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Mern Demo",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "if-env NODE_ENV=production && npm run start:prod || npm run start:dev",
    "start:prod": "babel-node server.js",
    "start:dev": "concurrently \"nodemon --ignore 'client/*'\" \"npm run client\"",
    "client": "cd client && npm run start",
    "install": "cd client && yarn install",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "alphavantage": "^1.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "brain.js": "^1.6.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "if-env": "^1.0.4",
    "mdbreact": "^4.8.5-patch.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.0",
    "newsapi": "^2.4.0",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "webhoseio": "^1.0.2"
  }
}`

Comment: Heroku doesn't perform minification last time I checked, you'll have to elaborate on what exactly the tool is you're using to minify on the remote side.

Comment: Please share your package.json file

Comment: As far as I know, nothing. How can I look into this to add this tool?

Comment: I've updated the question above to show the package.json

Comment: Cheers! So you're running the build on heroku then! Can you please do 'node -v' see what's your node version?

Comment: I'm running v10.9.0

Comment: Excellent! Can you please update your package json with "engines" : { "node" : "10.9.0" } } - add this as after the dependencies section?

Comment: I've added that in. I'm currently still getting that error from Heroku.

Comment: Is this app written in TypeScript? (The server side?)

Comment: No, I only have react on the frontend

Comment: If that makes a different :)

Comment: Well it looks like you are using babel-node to start your server - can you not just use 'node server.js' or use concurrently the way that you're using it for your dev box?

Comment: I actually added `babel-node` this in lieu of `node server.js` to try to solve this problem as per the suggestion made here: https://www.jaygould.co.uk/devops/2017/11/14/cloud-deployment-heroku-node-babel.html. Running it with `node server.js` gives me the same issue.

Comment: Soo - 2 more questions. Does this work on your local machine? And can you please do an 'npm -v'

Comment: Ask all the questions you need! My app works perfectly fine locally and its only Heroku that complains about this. My npm version is 6.5.0. Might I add if it helps, my lock files for both the root and client directory are yarn.lock.

Comment: Let's add "npm": "6.5.0" to the engines part as well. so it should look like "engines": { "node" : "10.9.0", "npm": "6.5.0" }

Comment: Added it in. No luck, unfortunately.

Comment: Well the only thing that's remaining is start the way that you're starting the dev server. Are you building when you're starting your dev server? Do you run everything that's run in heroku? What happens if you run npm run build?

Comment: Also, I am not building when running the dev server.

Comment: Try building it locally and it fails with the same error correct?

Comment: Yes exactly. It has to do with my webpack configuration and I’m having trouble getting to forgive this dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by turning off minification in my Webpack config. Instead of using the CRA-preconfigured Webpack ES-Lint loader, I installed the HTML-Loader and set `loader` to that. Following, I set minimize to `false`. Here's how:

```
module: {
rules: [
  {
    use: [
      {
        options: {
          formatter: eslintFormatter,
          eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
          minimize: false,
        },
        loader: require.resolve('html-loader'),
      },
    ],}}
```